# How to write Korean in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, languages, polyglossia

Here's my mwe:
[image]

I keep getting the following error:
[image]

How can I write Korean in LaTeX? Also, I tried compiling with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX but I still get the same errors. Please help and thank you.

Comment: that is a warning not an error. Simply remove the line with inputenc to get rid of it. And don't show code as screenshot. Copy it into the question so that other can copy&paste and test it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help and I'll input my code next time. Sorry.

Comment: Is there a way to make it a sans serif type of font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don’t need both `babel` and `polyglossia`. Here is a document with `babel`, with `english` as the main language and `korean` as the secondary one, using different fonts (with `luatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{korean}

\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[korean]{rm}{Un Batang}

\begin{document}

English text. 한국어는 어근과 접사 등 특정 표지가
붙음에 따라 단어의 기능이 결정되는 교착어로 분류된다.
More English text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Line breaking is by default character based, but this can be changed. In my tests, `kotex` seems to be compatible with `babel`.

Answer (score 4):

You asked,

> How can I write Korean in LaTeX?

As long as you have suitable OpenType fonts at hand and know how to load the `fontspec` package -- either directly or indirectly (via, say, the `polyglossia` package) -- and know how to execute `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` directives, there's really nothing special to do in order to write Korean in LaTeX.

If the `polyglossia` package is loaded, one could use `\textkorean` to apply Korean-specific typographic rules to short strings. E.g., compare the outputs of `\today` and `\textkorean{\today}` in the screenshot shown below. (Writing `\textkorean{Hello World}` does nothing special, i.e., it outputs "Hello World".) One would employ `\begin{korean}` and `\end{korean}` mainly to typeset longer passages, e.g., one or more paragraphs of text, in a way that implements Korean-specific formatting rules.

By "suitable" OpenType fonts, I mean a font that provides both Latin glyphs and Korean glyphs. `Noto Serif KR` and `Noto Sans KR` satisfy this condition.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{korean}

%% Next, load suitable Opentype fonts, e.g., Noto Serif/Sans KR.
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifluatex
   \setmainfont{Noto Serif KR}
   \setsansfont{Noto Sans  KR}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\else\ifxetex 
   \defaultfontfeatures{Path=/Users/mico/Library/Fonts/} % set as needed
   \setmainfont{NotoSerifKR-Regular}[BoldFont=NotoSerifKR-Bold]
   \setsansfont{NotoSansKR-Regular}[BoldFont=NotoSansKR-Bold,
                                    Scale=MatchUppercase]
\fi\fi

\begin{document}
Hello World. 헬로월드 

\textbf{Hello World. 헬로월드} 

\textsf{Hello World. 헬로월드} 

\textbf{\textsf{Hello World. 헬로월드}}

\today\ vs.\ \textkorean{\today}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I copied and pasted your code but I keep getting multiple errors regarding it cannot find NotoSerifKRRegular and NotoSansKRRegular. I just have to make sure my compiler is either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX right?

Comment: @cantor'ssloth - Yes, in order to load the `polyglossia` package, you *must* compile the document with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. How to organize the arguments of `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` under XeLaTeX can (and often does) depend significantly on the operating system that's in use. I happen to use MacOS 12.6.1 "Monterey", and fonts supplied by Google -- such as the Noto Serif and Noto Sans font families -- happen to have been installed in `/Users/mico/Library/Fonts/`. Try the LuaLaTeX approach first on your system, as LuaLaTeX is a bit more relaxed about how fonts can be loaded.

Comment: Ok, I use Windows11 and neither one of the compilers is working. I keep getting the same errors. Does Windows11 require a workaround?

Comment: @cantor'ssloth - Sorry, but I don't do Windows. By the way, have you checked that the [Noto Serif KR](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif+KR) and [Noto Sans KR](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+KR) fonts are installed on your computer? (If they're not, that would explain why your system can't find NotoSerifKRRegular and NotoSansKRRegular.) You may download the Noto Serif/Sans KR fonts for free from Google. After downloading and installing the two font families, be sure to activate them as appropriate for Windows 11.

Comment: @cantor'ssloth you can install noto fonts for windows but you can use any font you use in a browser or Word processor, you do not have to use noto fonts